# Can Yarn return a simple Semver version of installed package?

Tags: yarnpkg

Is it possible to make Yarn spit out a simple Semver version of the installed package via the CLI?

I've tried the following.

```bash
yarn list --pattern typescript
# too much info

yarn info typescript -A
# too much info.    

yarn --version typescript 
# Gives Yarn version, not TS.
```

Wanting Yarn to just spit out a simple Semver version. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
yarn info typescript *specific field you want to read*
```

In your case:

```
yarn info typescript version
```

Returns for me:

```
yarn info v1.19.1arn info typescript version
warning package.json: No license field
4.7.4
Done in 0.66s.
```

[see here](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/info)

Hope that's what you need!

Comment: `yarn info` returns the info from the package registry, not what's currently installed